# How to add NFT Royalties Feature to a marketplace

Tags: solidity, blockchain, dapps, nft, royalties

I'm currently working on an NFT marketplace, and I would like for creators to be able to add a certain percentage as royalties for future sales like rarible does. So what I wanna know is do I add this feature in the NFT smart contract i.e when the user mints an item, royalties information is added before calling the _mint() function

or in the Market smart contract i.e when the user list the item on the marketplace the royalties information is added to the item struct and then the market contract is responsible for making the royalties transfer when the sale is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [EIP-2981 NFT Royalty Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981).

> A standardized way to retrieve royalty payment information for non-fungible tokens (NFTs) to enable universal support for royalty payments across all NFT marketplaces and ecosystem participants.

Comment: That doesn't explain how exactly it should be applied in a solidity project though.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker The standard explain how a contract should provide royalty info, then it is up to the markets how to use it. The specs explain some use cases that it covers.